# Laravel - Check if @yield empty or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to check into a blade view if @yield have content or not?

I am trying to assign the page titles in the views:

```
@section("title", "hi world")
```

So I would like to check in the main layout view... something like:

```
<title> Sitename.com {{ @yield('title') ? ' - '.@yield('title') : '' }} </title>
```

Comment: why not pass the title as a variable

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is probably a prettier way to do this. But this does the trick.

```
@if (trim($__env->yieldContent('title')))
    <h1>@yield('title')</h1>
@endif
```

Comment: It would be even prettier to create a new blade directive for that instead using the hidden variables in your code.

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade

Comment: Now `hasSection` this is far better, you might consider to edit this answer. (see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36671780/2666094)

Comment: what to do if I had to appy OR? like hasSection('section1' or 'section2')? Is there anything?

Comment: Is there a similar technique for stack/push elements ?

Answer (score 125):

For those looking on it now (2018+), you can use :

```
@hasSection('name')
   @yield('name')
@endif
```

See : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#control-structures

Comment: Note that the documentation was removed at some point between 5.2 and 5.4, but it was added back in 5.5.

Answer (score 96):

In Laravel 5 we now have a `hasSection` method we can call on a `View` facade.

You can use `View::hasSection` to check if `@yeild` is empty or not:

```
<title>
    @if(View::hasSection('title'))
        @yield('title')
    @else
        Static Website Title Here
    @endif
</title>
```

This conditional is checking if a section with the name of title was set in our view.

**Tip**: I see a lot of new artisans set up their title sections like this:

```
@section('title')
Your Title Here
@stop
```

but you can simplify this by just passing in a default value as the second argument:

```
@section('title', 'Your Title Here')
```

The `hasSection`method was added [April 15, 2015](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/b24f6916f51c1c2689b60151970101d1f5649306).

Comment: This is definitely the Laravel 5+ way of doing it - super easy.

Answer (score 22):

Given from the docs:

```
@yield('section', 'Default Content');
```

Type in your main layout e.g. "app.blade.php", "main.blade.php", or "master.blade.php"

```
<title>{{ config('app.name') }} - @yield('title', 'Otherwise, DEFAULT here')</title>
```

And in the specific view page (blade file) type as follows:

```
@section('title')
My custom title for a specific page
@endsection
```

Comment: This is best practice, addresses the root issue of the question, more readable and (fractionally) more efficient.

Comment: No. OP wants to check the parameter so they can add a "-" character in the template. This syntax and the answer doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 10):

```
@hasSection('content')
  @yield('content')
@else
  \\Something else
@endif
```

see "Section Directives" in [If Statements - Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply check if the section exists:

```
if (isset($__env->getSections()['title'])) {

    @yield('title');
}
```

And you can even go a step further and pack this little piece of code into a Blade extension: http://laravel.com/docs/templates#extending-blade

Comment: Here's the code to make a Blade extension for this - i.e. `@ifSection('title')`: https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/6acf7aa12e084c67fc74

Answer (score 4):

Complete simple answer

```
<title> Sitename.com @hasSection('title') - @yield('title') @endif </title>
```

Comment: Yes, just wanted to provide a full working answer that only displayed the "-" if there was a title to display.

Thought it might save others time if they could just cut and paste

Comment: Thanks for that

**Answer the question**
Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that

Answer (score 4):

New in Laravel 7.x -- `sectionMissing()`:

```
@hasSection('name')
   @yield('name')
@else
   @yield('alternative')
@endif
```

Check if section is missing:

```
@sectionMissing('name')
   @yield('alternative')
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with the solution:

```html
@section('bar', '')
@hasSection('bar')
<div>@yield('bar')</div>
@endif
//Output
<div></div>
```

The result will be the empty `<div></div>`

Now, my suggestion, to fix this, is

```html
@if (View::hasSection('bar') && !empty(View::yieldContent('bar')))
<div>@yield('bar')</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@if (View::hasSection('my_section'))
    <!--Do something-->
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `View::hasSection` to check if a section is defined and `View::getSection` to get the section contents without using the `@yield` Blade directive.

```
<title>{{ View::hasSection('title') ? View::getSection('title') . ' - App Name' : 'App Name' }}</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, but you have options, like using a view composer to always provide a $title to your views:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $title = Config::get('app.title');

    $view->with('title', $title ? " - $title" : '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not pass the title as a variable `View::make('home')->with('title', 'Your Title')` this will make your title available in `$title`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do:

layout.blade.php

`<title> Sitename.com @section("title") Default @show </title>`

And in subtemplate.blade.php:

```
@extends("layout")

@section("title") My new title @stop
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to check is to not use the shortcut '@' but to use the long form: Section.

```
<?php
  $title = Section::yield('title');
  if(empty($title))
  {
    $title = 'EMPTY';
  }

  echo '<h1>' . $title . '</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: It does not help anyone if no explanation is given as to why this was down voted.

Comment: Maybe cause its not the blade way.

Comment: I beg to differ; specifically in Laravel 3 'blade.php' states:

'The Blade @yield statement is a shortcut to the Section::yield method.'

There is nothing wrong with extracting functionality for your own purposes.

Comment: Testing this does not seem to work for me though.  I would opt for `$__env->getSections()['title']` instead.

Comment: Laravel has evolved since then and I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better way. This post is now almost two years old and two versions behind.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Collin Jame's answer, if it is not obvious, I would recommend something like this:

```
<title>
  {{ Config::get('site.title') }} 
  @if (trim($__env->yieldContent('title')))
    - @yield('title')
  @endif
</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have an enclosing code, which you only want to have included in that section is not empty. For this problem I just found this solution:

```
@if (filled(View::yieldContent('sub-title')))
    <h2>@yield('sub-title')</h2>
@endif
```

The title H2 gets only displayed it the section really contains any value. Otherwise it won't be printed...