# Laravel how to catch yielded area has some content?

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I wonder how can we get yield() content. What if yield() area is empty. For example

```
<body>
@include('mains.includes.header')
@yield('content')
@include('mains.includes.footer') 
</body>
```

If nothing pass anything to the yield('content') area, website displays header and footer. Instead i would like to abort 404 or smt. I wonder i can try to do like that?

```
<body>
@include('mains.includes.header')
@if(!empty(yield('content')))
@yield('content')
@else
@php abort(404) @endphp
@endif
@include('mains.includes.footer') 
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412738/laravel-check-if-yield-empty-or-not

Comment: It's not the purpose of a template to throw a 404. Use and/or extend the respective controller instead.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you could use this in your blade files, though if you are trying to show 404 page that can be done by using error handlers in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors

```
 @if(!View::hasSection('content'))
 // more blade stuff here
 @endif
```